# Generate type definitions from JS React components that use `prop-types`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

We have a component like:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

export default class Tooltip extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    /**
     * Some children components
     */
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    /**
     * Some property
     */
    someProp: PropTypes.string,
   }

   .....

}
```

Is there some tooling to enable type generation to a typescript declaration file to generate something like:

```
interface ITooltip {
    children: React.Node,
    someProp: string
}
```

Some reference:

- https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react/issues/1346
- https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen
- https://github.com/KnisterPeter/react-to-typescript-definitions

Comment: Have you find a solution (to achieve it as part of the build process)?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I did not, and I have moved on from that project.

Comment: @Sagivb.g Did you solve it? I encoutered on same problem.

Comment: @Mormen Unfortunately no

Answer (score 3):

If you install `@types/prop-types` you can use the `InferProps` generic type to generate types like that:

```
import { InferProps } from "prop-types"

type ITooltip = InferProps<typeof Tooltip.propTypes>

// or interfaces if that's what you prefer:
// interface ITooltip extends InferProps<typeof Tooltip.propTypes> {}
```

The type is more verbose due to typings of `prop-types`, but it gives you the correct result in usage.

Comment: I am hoping there is a way to generate ts declaration files as part of a build process. This is a package which is written in `js`, that is imported into a `ts` project.

Comment: The TypeScript compiler is doing that for you. With the `-d` or `--declaration` you generate a `d.ts` file with all your exported members.

Comment: But will `tsc` generate `d.ts` files for props defined only via `prop-types` in `js` only React components, that is the workflow I am looking for.